# On boundary values of ${\cal C}^\infty_c$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, smooth-functions

The issue is about defining compact-supported smooth functions over the real semi-axis, such that they are null at the origin.
My professor said it can be done in two equivalent ways:

1. $f \in {\cal C}^\infty_c\{(0, +\infty)\}$
2. $f \in {\cal C}^\infty_c\{[0, +\infty)\},$ such that $f(0)=0$.

Why is it necessary to specify $f(0)=0$ in the 2nd case?

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty understanding?  Do you understand why functions in the first class must converge to zero at zero?  Do you understand why functions in the second class can be non-zero at zero if you allow them to be?  Do you understand how to map the first class bijectively onto the second class?

Comment: @user941248 I think you've already answered, but you deleted your previous comment. Anyway, what I don't understand is how could a smooth function be different from $0$ at $x=0$ when it's supposed to be $0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f \in \mathcal C^\infty_c\{[0, +\infty)\}$ means first of all that the domain of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$. Such an $f$ isn't even defined for inputs below $0$, much less having value $0$ there as you expect.

For example, the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{1/(x-1)}& x\in [0,1)\\0&x\in[1,\infty)\end{cases}$$

is in $\mathcal C^\infty_c\{[0, +\infty)\}$. I'm sure you are familiar with why it is smooth, and its support is $[0,1]$, which is compact. Clearly, $f(0) = \frac 1e \ne 0$.

Thus you need to specify $f(0) = 0$ if you want this condition to hold.

I'm not sure where your professor was going with those two sets, but let me point that they are not the same, even if we do the obvious continuous extension of the functions in $\mathcal C^\infty_c\{(0, +\infty)\}$ to the domain $[0,\infty)$. This only makes $$\mathcal C^\infty_c\{(0, +\infty)\} \subset \{f \in \mathcal C^\infty_c\{[0, +\infty)\} \mid f(0) = 0 \}$$
There are functions in the right hand set whose restrictions to $(0,\infty)$ are not in $\mathcal C^\infty_c\{(0, +\infty)\}$, such as

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}e^{1/(x^2-x)}& x\in (0,1)\\0&x\in\{0\}\cup[1,\infty)\end{cases}$$
The restriction of $g$ to $(0,\infty)$ has support $(0,1]$, which is not compact.

Comment: I'd even say $C_c^\infty([0,\infty))$ is a bit confusing. For instance is the function $f(x)=\sin(x)\eta(x)$ in this space (where $\eta$ is a smooth function such that $\eta\equiv 1$ near zero and $\eta\equiv 0$ near infinity)? Is $\eta$ in it even?

Comment: Isn't the support always closed? By definition ${\rm supp} f \equiv \{ \overline{x \in {\rm dom} f \ | \ f(x) \neq 0} \} $. Maybe there is a more general definition... I don't know.

Comment: @ric.san - yes, the support is closed. But "closed" is only defined relative to the ambient topological space. Just like in $\Bbb R$, the set $(-\infty, 0]$ is closed but not compact, so in $(0,\infty)$, the set $(0,1]$ is closed but not compact.

Comment: @Jose27 - If by "$\eta \equiv 0$ near infinity" you mean that there is an $M$ such that $\eta(x) = 0$ for all $x > M$, then yes $\eta$ and $\sin(x)\eta(x)$ are both in $C_c^\infty([0,\infty))$, regardless of what values $\eta$ takes on near $0$. The support of $\eta$ is a closed subset of the compact set $[0,M]$, and therefore must be compact itself. And if $g$ is any smooth function on $[0, \infty)$, then $g\eta$ is also smooth, and the support of $g\eta$ is itself a closed subset of the support of $\eta$, and so must also be compact.